# How much should I rely on Geometry shaders in WebGL?

Tags: webgl, geometry-shader, compatibility

Geometry shaders appear to have been introduced in 3.2, which makes me wonder how common 3.2-enabled cards are, including support for Geometry shaders within WebGL contexts.

Will I be cutting out a large portion of viewers by requiring the use of a geometry shader?

Comment: Awh shoot, just realized [Geometry shaders aren't supported in WebGL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641119/webgl-geometry-shader-equivalent). :|

Comment: Why not make that your answer. Then this question is not as purposeless as it seems. (or delete offcourse)

Comment: @joojaa done and done :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WebGL doesn't even currently support geometry shaders, so to directly answer the question: 100% of all users.